# Error when trying to change MUI (Material UI) checkbox value via state and onChange in React/NextJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

The error is: TypeError: filters.brand.find is not a function

and it says that it happened here:

checked={

> 173 |     filters.brand.find((item) => item === brand)
> |                  ^
> 174 |         ? true
> 175 |         : false
> 176 | }

Below is what I'm trying to achieve:

I'm building an e-commerce site using NextJS and amongst other features, users can choose to view products by category or subcategory. On either of these pages, users can choose to refine the results even further using filters. One of these filters should allow the user to display only the items of a certain brand/s.

These brands are presented to the user as checkboxes. So a checked checkbox should mean "include this brand" otherwise do not:

```
<FormGroup>
                        {brands.map((brand) => (
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                    <Checkbox
                                        size="small"
                                        name={brand}
                                        checked={
                                            filters.brand.find((item) => item === brand)
                                                ? true
                                                : false
                                        }
                                        onChange={() => handleBrandChange(brand)}
                                    />
                                }
                                label={brand}
                                key={brand}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </FormGroup>
```

btw: I tried using "includes" instead of "find" above but still ran into the same problem.

The initial value for filter.brand comes from the URL's query string.

```
const { query, ...router } = useRouter();

    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
        brand: query.brand ? (typeof query.brand === "string" ? [query.brand] : query.brand) : [],
    });
```

I check if the query string has "brand", which could either come back as a string or an array. If it is there, I check its type. If it's a string, I set filter.brand's value to an array with that string inside otherwise I take it as is. If the query string does not have a brand, I assign filter.brand an empty array.

btw, I am leaving out most of the code that is of no relevance to this problem.

Below is how I tried to handle the change (when the user clicks on a brand checkbox):

```
const handleBrandChange = (brand) => {
        const brandArray = filters.brand;

        if (brandArray.find((item) => item === brand)) {
            setFilters({ ...filters, brand: brandArray.filter((item) => item !== brand) });
        } else setFilters({ ...filters, brand: brandArray.push(brand) });
    };
```

and below is what should happen every time the state changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const urlObject = {
            query: {
                category: query.category,
                sortBy: filters.sortBy,
                maxPrice: filters.maxPrice,
            },
        };

        if (filters.brand.length > 0) urlObject.query.brand = filters.brand;

        if (query.subcategory) {
            urlObject.pathname = "/[category]/[subcategory]";
            urlObject.query.subcategory = query.subcategory;
        } else {
            urlObject.pathname = "/[category]";
        }

        router.push(urlObject);
    }, [filters, query.subcategory, query.category]);
```

Sorry for the messy question. I am not used to asking questions on here (this is only my second time), I have not been coding for that long and English is not my first language. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that somehow `filters.brand` ends up not being an array. Perhaps logging its value just before rendering `<FormGroup>` might give you some ideas.

Comment: @tromgy I've already tried that unfortunately. I tried console.log(filters) inside of a useEffect and sure enough filters.brand is an array. This is the case whether the URL has ?brand=brandName or not. When I type in the URL into the browser manually it works with no issues. The problem only begins as soon as I click on one of the checkboxes.